# How to get link text when the link is clicked? I am using Link Button

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I am using almost 2000 Link Buttons on a webpage.When i click any of the link buttons,it should direct me to next page and the TEXT of that link button should be stored in some session variable which can be used wherever i want.I am able to do so but the problem is i have to do it for all the 2000 click events.Is there a way i can do it without writing so much of the code? I have almost no knowledge of javascript and jquery.

Comment: Set the OnClick event of all buttons to the same event in the code behind.

Comment: Why dont you try client side technologies like Jquery, Web programming is much easier with them

Comment: Ahh,Interesting.So i should just change the OnClick event attribute of all the link buttons.and then just write one code for that event in code-behind? Right?

Comment: @Mash Yes, that is pretty much the idea. You can access the `LinkButton` being clicked by casting the `object sender` to a `LinkButton` object, and get the `Text`, or any other property from the button then.